# What’s going on “under the hood” in this Samba transfer? Specifically the occasional dips in transfer speed?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, samba

I have a Windows 7 system with a Samba shared folder and an Ubuntu system that has access to that folder.  Using the Ubuntu system I copy a 68GB folder (SSD) to the Windows machine (HDD) which executes fine.

On the Ubuntu machine I see the transfer speed at ~200-350Mib/sec and on the windows machine I see Network utilization around 80-90%. However, there are dips where the transfer stops for several seconds at a time.  I can only guess that the SSD is maxing out its speed and the Windows machine is filling RAM then during the dip is writing to the HDD to get ready to fill the RAM again.

Here’s the Windows network graph:

[image]

My questions are, is this the most efficient way to transfer the data?  Wouldn’t it be more efficient for the Ubuntu system to throttle its read speed to sync with the write speed of the windows machine? If so, is this a limitation in Samba?  Would I see the same behavior if Ubuntu had a shared folder and I executed the copy command from Windows instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely the transfer slowing temporarily to allow the slower disk to catch up on writes/reads.

Any transfer will only ever run as fast as the slowest component... in this case, probably the windows spindle disk.

If you open Performance Monitor and look at disk activity in windows, you will see teh disk was probably being hammered all the time and when the write-buffer fills, the disk needs to slow/stop accepting new data for few milliseconds so that it can catch up.

Changing the copy method will not greatly affect anything - the transfers will only ever be as fast as the slowest component whether you do it via unc or mapped drive, command line or GUI.

If the Ubuntu box did any sort of throttling, it would only add to the delays due to the additional overhead of having to calculate when/if to keep resetting speed limits.  Your best bet it just to let it get on with it.